# Spring Boot: Configure a url prefix for RestControllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I'm no Spring expert, and being the black box that it is, it's been hard trying to figure things out on my own, even with Spring's documentation. Sometimes, I just have no idea what I'm looking for in order to start my search...

In my Spring Boot application, I'm trying to figure out how to configure a unique url prefix for all of my RestControllers.

All I'm really after here is to have my static content served up from the root context, "/", but have my RestController endpoints accessible from a different context, say "/api/*".

I know how to change the app's default context through application.properties, but that isn't quite what I'm after. I'm showing my ignorance here when it comes to servlets, mappings, etc, as I say that I'm trying to get two different contexts for two different types of content.

Comment: Why use different URLs instead of serving different representations from the same URLs using content negotiation?

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot and Spring Data Rest then I would suggest adding this line to the _application.properties_ :  `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that's a valid point, although it's common to have it separated as two (or more applications). Let's assume you want to handle (1) a Website serving HTML/CSS/JS and (2) a REST API. On top of your controllers you define "the context" by using `@RequestMapping` (you can't have two, so those will be in different controllers, again, depending on what you are trying to achieve):

- `@RequestMapping(/web)`
- `@RequestMapping(/api/v1)`

...and then inside those controllers, in the methods, you ca assign the "rest of the URL", again by using `@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

e.g. `/web/index`, `/web/error`; as well as: `/api/v1/something`, `/api/v1/something-else`.

Having a nice package convention will help you not to get lost with so many *controllers*.

**NOTE:** Remember you DO NOT need to repeat the same context in every single method, but just "rest of the URL".

Comment: Thank you very much! I was hoping for a more global way to configure it, but I'd completely spaced being able to give the controller a path, not just its methods. This works, and is quite simple enough. =)