# How to prepend some text to all controller URL in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url, request-mapping

We have some already developed REST APIs in SpringBoot.

Now we want to prepend some text (version of API eg `/v1/`) to all the `@RequestMapping`.

Is there any way of doing this except prepending `/v1/` to every `@RequestMapping`

---

example: Current RequestMapping `/employess` and `/cars/1/driver`

Need to build like this `/v1/employess` and `/v1/cars/1/driver`

Comment: Could you add an example of how your current mappings are set ?

Comment: @Arnaud Updated the question

Comment: @MehrajMalik Did you have a chance to test my solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use such property in your `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/v1
```

or you can have a base controller class and extend it with all your controller classes

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "${rest.api.version}")
public class MyAbstractController {
}
```

and store `rest.api.version` in your `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in at least 2 ways.

Option 1: extend AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer as below:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/v1/*" };
    }

}
```

Option 2: add a request mapping on class level on the controllers you want the version prepended as below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class Controller {
}
```

I would go for option 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append every request with "/v1", You can do so by using @RequestMapping annotation at the class level, in this way all the incoming calls(which has "/v1" in it) will land in your controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class YourController {
}
```

Comment: I asked for All Controller, not just one controller!

Comment: Found the solution : https://mhdevelopment.wordpress.com/2016/10/03/spring-restcontroller-specific-basepath/

Comment: possible duplicate of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801351/how-to-configure-a-default-restcontroller-uri-prefix-for-all-controllers/39716758#39716758